# Spy on a class variable

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

I have a `<div>` element that has a `(click)` event attached to it which toggles some class variable, like the following:

```
<div (click)="some-variable-name = !some-variable-name"></div>
```

For testing the click event first I have to grab the `div` event by its CSS class, something like this:

```
let some-var = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.css-class-name'));
```

So is there a way by which I can spy on the class variable `some-variable-name` and check if it changes on the click event while testing, with something like this:

```
let switch-some-variable-name = component.some-variable-name;
some-var.nativeElement.click();
fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
expect(component.some-variable-name).toEqual(!switch-some-variable-name);
```

Comment: Aside from `.not.toEqual(...)`, what's wrong with what you have? Spies are for things that you call.

Comment: right, I figured that! So if I can't test it with spy, then how can I test if its getting toggled on the click event?

Comment: Exactly how you suggest in the question - store the before value, then assert that the after value is different.

Comment: I get it now! I don't need to spy on a class variable, I can just compare the variable changes before and after the click events. Thanks!